# iPad parallax flickering

Tags: ipad, parallax

I am using a parallax effect with javascript but I'm having issues with iPad.

I know the "$(window).scroll" is not triggered on webkit touch devides - only when we release the screen - so i'm using:

```
window.addEventListener("touchmove", triggerScroll, false);

function triggerScroll(event)
{       
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();//event.touches[0].pageY; //window.pageYOffset();


$("#allCanvas .divCanvas").each(function(index, element) {
    var speed = $(element).data('speed');
    var initialTop = $(element).data('initialtop');     
    $(element).css('top', initialTop-(scrollTop*speed));

});

}
```

The problem is that it flickers the .divCancas a few pixels to the top or bottom depending if I'm scrolling to top or down.

I tracked the TOP value passed on $(element).css('top', initialTop-(scrollTop*speed)); and it's every time correct. The correct "TOP" value, eventhough webkit move it for a few milleseconds to the wrong position.

I tried also:
-"margin-top" rather than "top" with no difference.
-Removing all other objects and making the ".each" loop through only one div, so I guess is not a jQuery performance issue.

Has anyone came across this problem?

Many thanks
Diego

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using some of the -webkit css animation features... these run very smoothly on iOS devices. Here's a great demo of that (webkit only): http://jibjub.com/demo/HTML5/cube.html